# What is the process behind opening a file in UNIX?

Tags: unix, filesystems

[image: SYSTEM TABLE INDEXED BY FILE DESCRIPTOR]
[image: SYSTEM TABLE INDEXED BY I-NUMBER]

***what happens when a user opens a file. For instance, if a user opens /home/example.txt, what does the UNIX file system do in order to find the file's contents?***

According to my limited understanding,

1. i-number of root is 1. OS will look up for i-node associated with i-number in i-list. i-node of root directory contains additional information like permission,size,address,identification,who created it,when it was created etc.OS will get address of roots' directory table from i-node.
2. In the roots' directory table ,OS will search for i-number associated with name "home".i-number of home (let's say 10).OS will then search for i-node associated with 10 and will find address of home's directory table.
3. In home directory table, OS will search for the name example.txt and will get i-number of it which again will be used to access i-node of example.txt from i-list.

Additionally,can you the difference between these two highlighted.
My own understanding says that these are two different tables

1. file table which keeps track of all the open files indexed by file descriptor.
2. i-list indexed by i-number which maps it to i-node.

Reference:

- https://dsf.berkeley.edu/cs262/unix.pdf . Dennis M. Ritchie and Ken
  Thompson .Electronic version recreated by Eric A. Brewer University of
  California at Berkeley

Comment: It looks like you got it just fine. Also when quoting from somewhere, please include a reference to the source.